# Invalid imageTag error from ImageStore.getBase64ForTag

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get a base64 image from facebook profile picture.

```
getImageFromFacebook() {
 const imageURL = this.props.userInfo.picture;
  Image.getSize(imageURL, (width, height) => {
   var imageSize = {width, height};
   ImageEditor.cropImage(imageURL, imageSize, (imageURI) => {
    console.log(imageURI);
    ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(imageURI, (base64Data) => {
      this.setState({pictureBase64: base64Data});
      ImageStore.removeImageForTag(imageURI);
    }, (reason) => console.log(reason) )
   }, (reason) => console.log(reason) )
  }, (reason) => console.log(reason))
}
```

I am following the steps described in this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1158:

1. Use Image.getSize(uri) to get the image dimensions.
2. Use ImageEditor.cropImage(uri, cropData) to store a copy of the image in the ImageStore (if you pass the width and height you got in step 1) then cropImage won't actually crop the image, although it may still make a copy of it.
3. Use ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(uri) to get the base64 data of the new image (pass the uri you got from the cropImage function, not the original).
4. Don't forget to call ImageStore.removeImageForTag(uri) once you're done to delete the copy.

Although the ImageEditor.cropImage returns a valid URI (rct-image-store://0), ImageStore.getBase64ForTag fails with a reason:

```
code: "ERCTERRORDOMAIN0",
domain: "RCTErrorDomain",
message: "Invalid imageTag: rct-image-store://0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found the error!
imageSize should be set like this:

```
  var imageSize = {
    size: {
      width,
      height
    },
    offset: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    },
  };
```